# PYQT5 set all labels to black

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have several checkboxes which control various procedures, once the code has run all checkboxes which were successful are coloured green e.g. `self.cbMarkerDetection.setStyleSheet("color: green;")` as it goes to the next job I want to reset the colour back to black. Obviously I could do `self.cbMarkerDetection.setStyleSheet("color: black;")` for every checkbox... but I'm hoping there is some way to do something like:

```
for checkbox in allcheckboxes:
    self.checkbox.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
```

A simple coded example, two check boxes, when selected it goes green in colour, when I click the other check box I want all to change back to black, imagine checkboxes a-g, when checkbox (or a button if you like) is selected/checked the selected goes green when checkbox z (or a button) is selected/clicked all the existing check boxes turn black. As stated above, I could list all the checkboxes and set them black, but I'm looking for a quicker way with less code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QCheckBox, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize    

class ExampleWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(140, 40))    
        self.setWindowTitle("Checkbox") 

        self.a = QCheckBox("box1",self)
        self.a.stateChanged.connect(self.clickBox)
        self.a.move(20,20)
        self.a.resize(320,40)

        self.b = QCheckBox("box2",self)
        self.b.stateChanged.connect(self.clickBox)
        self.b.move(20,80)
        self.b.resize(320,40)

    def clickBox(self, state):

        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            print('Checked')
            self.checkbox.setStyleSheet("color: green;")
        else:
            print('Unchecked')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = ExampleWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Comment: your question is unclear, please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I assumed it was a rather straight forward question, I've now complicated it by adding a load of code, altered from some online code.

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with your proposed looping solution.

Comment: use `for checkbox in [self.a, self.b]:` or maybe `for checkbox in self.findChildren(QCheckBox):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use [`findChildren()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren):

```
for checkbox in self.findChildren(QCheckBox, options=Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly):
    checkbox.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
```

If you have *other* checkboxes in your widget that should not included in the list, you can create an empty subclass and use that for the filter:

```
class MyCheckBox(QCheckBox): pass

# ...

self.a = MyCheckBox("box1", self)
# etc...
```

Then you use findChildren with the custom class name:

```
for checkbox in self.findChildren(MyCheckBox, options=Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly):
    checkbox.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
```

<sup>Note that using fixed geometries is discouraged, and you should prefer [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead.</sup>

Comment: replace `Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly` with `Qt.FindChildrenRecursively` and it works a charm!

Comment: @SpatialDigger I based my answer on your code, and I specifically used `FindDirectChildrenOnly` because you're creating children of the main window (which is not a good practice, but that's another point). If you are reparenting the widgets, then you should still use that flag but use `findChildren` on the parent of the check boxes, otherwise you can potentially find other similar widgets in children containers, unless you're *completely* sure that *all* of your QCheckBoxes match your search criteria, or you use a custom subclass as explained in the answer.